# T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/4) + O(1), what is T(n)?

Tags: complexity-theory, recurrence, asymptotic-complexity

How to solve this recurrence: `T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/4) + O(1)`

It doesn't seem like Master Method will help, as this is not in the form of `T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)`. And I got stuck for quite a while.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Akra Bazzi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method) is a much more powerful method than Master method.

Since the 'non-recursive' term is O(1), it amounts to solving the equation

`1/2^p + 1/4^p = 1`

And the answer you get will be `T(n) = Theta(n^p)`

I believe solving the above (quadratic in `1/2^p`) gives us `p = log_2 phi`  where phi is the golden ratio.

Computing that gives us `T(n) = Theta(n^0.694...)`